# Hangouts causes system to freeze & crash on Mint 18.3, dell Inspiron 15, Intel i7 7thGen

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7560 i7 and have dual booted Linux Mint 18.3. Running a BIOS version 1.3 from Intel's website. Video card is NVIDIA GeForce 940MX (4GB).

I am seeing that while using Google Hangouts, my machine randomly freezes. Sound to/from the call pauses first, then the screen freezes, and then the controls. I get a second or two before the controls freeze but there is hardly anything that can be done in those, the realisation that it is a freeze takes that time! (Fearing a freeze, I have switched to a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) a couple times on calls when everyone went on mute! :P). A few seconds later the screen goes blank too. The only way I can recover is by a hard reset, pressing down the power button a few seconds.

This does not happen every time. There is no specific state the machine has to be in, or the machine has to stay up. At times, it happens immediately after a restart and at times days go by without this issue. But when it happens, happens always when on Hangouts call.

I have tried different browser profiles, even with blank/fresh profiles. I have disabled hardware acceleration in chrome. Have also tried changing the browser to Opera. Nothing has worked so far.

I have tried switching between Intel card and Nvidia card. Tried using the the nouveau video driver and also the nvidia-384 driver.

Syslog is gibberish to me, could not find anything clearly pointing to an error. But [here](https://pastebin.com/gEiwCMsy) is one such log immediately after a force restart.
[here](https://pastebin.com/BWU1Nb6a) is today's log, the crash happened at 13:04.

Any idea how I can get it to work reliably?

(This laptop model suffers through a series of issues related to Linux drivers/BIOS: [error screens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914653/getting-hardware-error-processor-microcode-42-on-my-new-laptop), [sound issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916304/sound-fails-randomly-mostly-when-headphones-are-connected))

Comment: You should try changing distro. Something like Fedora or Antergos.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal thanks for your comment, but I cannot really understand reasoning. Would like to know what is so fundamentally broken with debian/ubuntu/mint in this context, that the move to Fedora/Arch be necessary.

Comment: i guess your graphics card isn't compatible with debian based distro. Just live boot some other OS and see if it works.